# if statement producing incorrect result

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am trying to see why this if statement is not producing the correct message. What is supposed to happen, is that if a user selects a row that is not marked in the db as 'In' then the first message is displayed. If they forget to select an address or service level, then the else if sould be triggered. If all cases are correct, then perform the else statement. However, what is happening, is that the first message is being triggered when it is selected the first time and fires the Error. If a user then forgets to select an address or service then that Error is fired. If the user then meets all conditions, instead of performing the else statement, it displays the $boxstatus error, even though the conditions are true. Can someone please point out my error? Many thanks

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header("Pragma: no-cache" );
header("Content-type: application/json");
$json = "";
if ($boxstatus!="In") {
  $json .= "{\"Error\": \"ERROR: The box must be in the archive to enable a retrieval.\"}";
}
else if ($service == '' || $address == '') {
  $json .= "{\"Error\": \"ERROR: You must select a retrieval address and a service level.\"}";
}
else {
$json .= "{\n";
$json .= "\"address\": \"".$address."\",\n";
$json .= "\"service\": \"".$service."\",\n";
$json .= "\"box\": \"".$box."\"\n";
//$json .= "box: [\"". implode('","', $box) ."\"]\n";
$json .= "}\n";
}
echo $json;
```

ajax if it helps:

```
$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               url: "boxretrieve.php",
               data: "items="+itemlist+columns,
               success: function(data){
               if (data.Error) jAlert(data.Error);
                    else {
                jAlert("You have successfully retrieved\n\rBox: "+custref+"\n\r"+
                                 "Address: "+address+"\n\r"+
                                 "Service: "+service+"\n\r"+
                                 "Destroydate: "+destroydate);
               $("#flex1").flexReload();
               }
               }
             });
```

+++++UPDATE+++++++

Changed the second error to Error2 and did a condition in the ajax and all is now well. Thanks to everyone for there help.

Comment: This looks correct to me. Have you tried tracking the value of `$boxstatus` ?

Comment: Can you try literally assign `In` value to `$boxstatus`? 'Coz I think there's nothing wrong with the condition, unless you want to happen a different behavior.

Comment: @kbok looking at this again, in the ajax perhaps what is happening, is that the data.Error is being displayed because I need to change the second error say from Error to Error2?

Comment: @domanokz please see posted comment.

Comment: You may want to use a network debugger to watch what is happening on the wires. I think the issue is on the PHP side.

Comment: @kbok firebug is showing the status as 'In' in the posted value and in the json tab it shows the error message for Error. But the more I look at the ajax above, it will always display the data.Error which in the php for both error messages' is Error. Now I could say change one from Error to Error2, but I do not know how to check for that condition in the ajax statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code by setting up your variables. It works! Nothing wrong with the conditions. You may want to check the result of your sql query or the way you show it on the browser.

```
<?php
$boxstatus = 'In';
$service = '';
$address = '';
$json='';

if ($boxstatus!="In") {
  $json .= "{\"Error\": \"ERROR: The box must be in the archive to enable a retrieval.\"}";
}
else if ($service == '' || $address == '') {
  $json .= "{\"Error\": \"ERROR: You must select a retrieval address and a service level.\"}";
}
else {
$json .= "{\n";
$json .= "\"address\": \"".$address."\",\n";
$json .= "\"service\": \"".$service."\",\n";
$json .= "\"box\": \"".$box."\"\n";
//$json .= "box: [\"". implode('","', $box) ."\"]\n";
$json .= "}\n";
}

echo $json;
?>
```

The output:

```
{"Error": "ERROR: You must select a retrieval address and a service level."}
```

I also used your jQuery, I just changed your `jAlert` with simple `alert`. It works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $.ajax
    ({
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       url: "test.php",
       success: function(data)
       {
           if (data.Error) 
           {
                alert(data.Error);
            }
            else 
            {
                alert("You have successfully retrieved\n\rBox: "+custref+"\n\r"+
                                 "Address: "+address+"\n\r"+
                                 "Service: "+service+"\n\r"+
                                 "Destroydate: "+destroydate);
               $("#flex1").flexReload();
           }
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

I don't know `jAlert`, but try using `alert` and tell me the result.

Comment: Please see my comment re ajax. The conditions are true to php but the ajax is outputting data.Error and both errors have the same name. For example, if I remove the else if error it displays correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You never assign a value to `$boxstatus` so it will never be `"In"`

(Also, **don't** build JSON by smashing strings together, use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) after putting together a proper data structure).

Comment: $boxstatus gets it's value from here in the php page: $boxstatus = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $dept = $row['department'];
          $box = $row['custref'];
    $customer = $row['customer'];
    $boxstatus = $row['status'];
    
}

Comment: This is how I normally use json: $results = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
$data['rows'][] = array(
'id' => $row['Id'],
'cell' => array($row['Id'], $row['rack'].$row['column'].'-'.$row['row'].'-'.$row['bay'], strtotime($row['destroy_date']))));
}
echo $json->encode($data);  This is just a cut example.